# How to add parameters to URL to show different content on the same page?

Tags: php, wordpress, url, parameters

I'm currently doing a WordPress project, and on one of the pages I have a form on that page which checks if the user inputted data is in the database. On submit I would like to add parameters to the URL of the same page, (i.e ?page=1) and show different content depending on the parameter of the url.

I have tried adding the parameters through the form's action attribute.

```
<form action="form.php?page=1" method="post" id="orderinfo">
```

But this leads to the following:

[image]

Where instead of adding parameters to the current page, it seems to create a new page.

Am I even going about this the right way?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a wordpress template_redirect hook to achive that. In your functions.php file you can add:

```
add_action('template_redirect', 'form_proccess');
function form_proccess() {
  if( isset($_POST['submit']) ) {
    // some validation here

    wp_safe_redirect( get_permalink().'?page=1'); exit;
  }
}
```

and in your form tag set action to empty string or the_permalink();

also page parameter may be reserved wordpress paramtere so you might want to try different one like success for example and another one for error if validation fails and redirect to error.

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

In Wordpress you need to register custom query string variables so that wordpress treats them accordingly.

You can do this by using a filter:

```
function additional_query_vars($vars) {
  $vars[] .= 'your_custom_variable';
  return $vars;
}
add_filter( 'query_vars', 'additional_query_vars' );
```

So now you have them added and Wordpress is aware of them, you can use `get_query_var` to retrieve them in your page or elsewhere.

Eg:

```
 $my_var= get_query_var('your_custom_variable');
```